# How to replace samba?

Tags: active-directory

What is the best way to replace 12.04's pre-loaded samba with centrify-enabled samba? I tried just uninstalling it, but it looks like nautilus is dependent on it. Any ideas? Do I need to uninstall nautilus too?

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to do this:

1. Make a package for samba with the changes you want, and install it as an upgrade. I think this is the better choice, but It is complicated the first time you do it, and you have to make sure that you create a new package each time there are changes to the package in the repository.
2. Make a package called samba that is empty, using equivs or similar. (for detailed instructions see http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/install/blocking-deb-dependencies.html ) and install samba by hand into /usr/local. The drawback of this approach is that samba is no longer managed by your package management system, you have to keep up with all security updates by hand, and If at some point a version of samba with a higher version then your dummy package comes along, you have to make sure it does not get installed.